# Opening a Mahjong business. Does 熬云 sound like a business name? Have no idea what a normal Chinese business name sounds like

Tags: word-choice

I believe this violates rules (at least it does in StackOverflow), because it's a subjective question.  But this is a really big decision so I just wanted to tap any resources I could before moving forward

I'm going to open a business that has private Mahjong rooms, open late (till 4AM), at the top floor of a building

For a business name I am thinking

**熬云**

Because 熬夜 is staying up late
运气 is luck
and 云 is clouds (top floor)

But my main problem is that I have no idea how it sounds.  I do not know any Chinese business names, what is normal, what sounds normal, what sounds ridiculous

So my question is:
Does **熬云** sound like a business name?  Especially one that has private rooms for mahjong

Comment: 运 might sound like a shipping company

Comment: Good call.  so just 熬云？If all else fails I can just pick an English name

Comment: Sounds like a cloud storage/cloud service company, like aliyun.com.

Comment: No, It doesn't sound like any name, maybe a villian's name in fantasy novel. Because 熬 is a negative word, no one use it to name something in tradition.

Comment: What do you think about 宝云?

Comment: You could always use a more descriptive name, such as 清龙家 (Qinglong jia) or 碰碰和亭 (Pengpenghu ting). The names refer to winning formations in majiang.

Comment: @AO 宝云 is an OK name, but sounds average, not special. 倪阔乐's idea is worth considering, that's much more interesting. (As you insist the ao sound) you may try 宝灯九莲 or something else.

Comment: I actually really like 清龙家.  My only hesitation is that because it's on the top floor in the downtown, I think somehow putting 云， 天， or something in the name would be nice. 
Does 清龙云 or 清龙天 sound good to you guys?  Sorry again for being so bothersome, my Chinese really isn't good and I just am not familiar with what Chinese business names sound like

Comment: @AO Then 青龙家 is perfect. 清龙云 or 清龙天 doesn't sound like a place. Moreover, 青龙 has suggested it's in the sky. (Hmm, I think the question can be closed now.)

Comment: er sorry, should it be 请or青？and could you explain how 青龙 suggests it's in the sky?  It sounds good to me; this is just going to be a huge investment for me so I want to be positive.  I will certainly close the question, I feel like I've made it stray way too far away from the original question

Comment: It's 清龙, as in pure dragon. Some dragons fly. 清龙 is a winning set of all numeric tiles plus an additional regular triple and pair:     

Comment: Could you post that as an answer and I'll mark it correct and close the question? ^^

Answer (score 3):

To me as a native speaker, there is a negative feeling about 熬. It means getting through(or endure) bad things(etc. pain, poor, sickness).
[see 熬's meaning here](http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/71AC.htm)

So maybe 熬 is just not the best choice. But considering your ID as "A O", you may like this "ao" sound very much. So my recommendation is to use 鏖 instead.([see 鏖's meaning here](http://www.zdic.net/z/26/js/93D6.htm)). It basically meaning a really long battle. As Mahjong is a really long battle on the table. Hope this helps.

Comment: yar I do like the "Ao", but i'm not married to it by any means.  I want it to sound more like a lounge/relaxing business, so I will continue looking at other characters.  I think I want to keep 云, though... gonna need to put more thought into it.  Thanks for the input :)

Comment: You are welcome. 云 is very good. 客似云来: customers flood in like clouds!

Comment: I agree, 熬 has a negative connotation so it should be avoided. The only minor problem is 鏖 is less common seen so some people cannot pronounce it correctly. Anyway 鏖云 does sound like a good casino name to me LOL

Comment: What do you think about 宝云?

Answer (score 0):

熬definitely sounds negative tiresome if not above neutral. 傲云maybe better choice and still has the sound/meaning if your original 熬云. Each hand starts with 13 tiles remind me a restaurant named "Lucky 13". Contradiction like that sometimes makes it stand out more or make it easy for people to remember. If the name is 清七对, everyone (who plays Mahjong) knows what it is.